# Token based authentication with Spring and JWT

Tags: java, spring, authentication, jwt

I am using spring security and JWT to implement the authentication/authorization system for my mobile application and I have a couple of doubts regarding the actual design of the system.
This is the authentication/authorization flow to allow users to access secured REST APIs:

1. The mobile application send a request to the /auth/token endpoint, along with the username and password of the user using the **basic** authentication scheme.
   The server authenticates the user returning an JWT access and refresh token.
2. All the subsequent requests to the protected resources represented by the endpoints /api/** are performed passing the access token, which is validated and trusted by the server. The logic to validate and trust the token is performed by a token filter executed before the spring's BasicAuthenticationFilter.
3. If the token is no more valid the client send the refresh token (JWT) to the /auth/refresh endpoint, which validates this token and if this is trusted returns a new access token. The /auth/refresh endpoint is publicly exposed, but it relies on the fact that the JWT signature must be valid and trusted.

I am also thinking to use OAuth, but I wanted to know if this architectural design can be used or it can be exposed to vulnerabilities or problem with scalability.
I am pretty new with the authentication system and I am trying to understand the correct way to implement one without having to use OAuth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe is basically the same as the oauth's password flow except for the missing clientid and secret.
The accesstoken and especially the refresh token should NEVER be forwarded to the actual applicaton, whether it's an app or a web application.

Always think in back and front channel. Front channels are where your application is running. Untrusted environments for example mobile phones, client side rendered applications and so on.

**These environments could be compromised.**

Therefore your accesstoken should always be saved on server side.

**But: You don't necessarily need a jwt for described usecase.** 

If you just need to login, it would be safer to just have a session login mechanism with a csrf validations checks enabled.

However if you want to go with an JWT I would suggest you to go with OAUTH's code flow or to make sure your access token is stored on trusted server side.

**For example:**

1. if the user signs in, he get's a session cookie in return.
2. After that he could also get an such called authCode for a special client (in this case your resourceservers or zuul proxy) and scopes like 'read_profile, make_payments'.
3. this authCode is now sent to your resourceserver or (zuul proxy sitting in front of your endpoints)
4. the resource server itself has it's own client credentials and now authenticates against the authentication server and get an accesstoken in exchange to an authcode.

In any case your user would be authenticated session-based on both sides and your resourceserver holds the accesstoken for the user.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Chris. Shouldn't the purpose of a token, especially signed ones like JWTs to be stateless and therefore not to be stored server side? Also because my access token has a 10 minutes expiration time. I also thought to store the refresh tokens in a database to allow to revoke them in case of  leak

Comment: if you want it stateless you would have to save the access token client side.
That's only recommended if you have trusted environments.
However, the purpose of having a stateless login is scalability and encapulation from authservice. Giving you the ability to give thirdparties access to your resources on behalf of the user. The JWT is securely stored in a session or database. If you scale it horizontally it will be shared between your instances without the need to recall the authentication service again.

Comment: always think, whoever has your accesstoken (refreshtoken) has full access to your resources. Accesstokens in front-channels is very very vulnerable thing.

Comment: btw. stack overflow acts the same :-) you're logged in by JWT. The accesstoken and refreshtokens are stored by stackoverflow, session-based.

Comment: you could also have a look on this, especially for mobile apps?... https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/08/22/okta-authjs-pkce

Comment: This post clarified some of my doubts, thank you! However it raised some other doubt now.

Comment: With this approach I will receive the tokens directly in my client(mobile), which I certainly do not want. Should I need a server in the middle (oauth client), containing the secret that acts as an intermediary between the mobile and auth/resource server? This would take credentials send them to the authorization server and get the code and then get the tokens and save them in session? Then every request will always pass through this server?

Comment: If you setup a client authenticating against the auth service the I would go with code flow. User credentials shouldn't be passed through the client.  User authenticates against auth service and client has its own credentials zu get an access token

Comment: Thank you for all the information, it is really helpful. Unfortunately, spring decided to remove the support for authorization servers which make difficult to create one. I found some solutions but some of them are not free and others are definitely more difficult to start with compare to spring boot

Comment: you're welcome. In my opinion spring boot supports the whole oauth2 authentication very well. I set up one myself with spring boot. You need the packages for spring cloud oauth2. You could follow these instructions... https://dzone.com/articles/build-an-oauth-20-authorization-server-with-spring

Comment: Would be nice if you accept my answer if it was helpful to you. :-) if you need some advices feel free to ask.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#dependencies is even better for getting started.

Comment: Thank you fo the resources. Today I started to implement my authorization server using spring but the AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter was given as deprecated. Then I read the roadmap and in fact they decided to remove support to the authorization server. Should I still implement it in spring even if it will no longer be supported therefore deprecated?

Comment: Good point. I must admit I wasn't of this change. Then I wouldn't go with spring anymore. I made a very good experience with springs oauth2 server. It was very stable and customizable. It's a bad mistake in my eyes to discontinue this feature. I would suggest to go with already existing products then.

Comment: Yes and apparently there is no much of a choice around, and implementing the entire protocol by hand it is not a suitable decision :(

Comment: Also an interesting article about openid connect that sits on top of oauth. May it's worth reading... https://www.ory.sh/run-oauth2-server-open-source-api-security/

Comment: without spring you shouldn't definitely setup one yourself. I would go with an existing product that can be customized to fit your needs instead. Maybe ory hydra looks promising for the oauth part.